# Can I define parameters from one method into another

Tags: c#

I am looking to design an interface method (a) that takes the parameters of another method (b), so if that method (b) changes, (a) will change also without me having to update it. Is this possible?

I'll try to explain with the following code

Method with parameters I'd like to call:

```
public int AddUser(string name, string description)
{
    ...
    return userID;
}
```

I then have two methods,

```
public void AddCustomerUser(int customerID, int UserID)
{
    //Do stuff
}

public void AddCustomerUser(int customerID, (string name, string description)<- these come from AddUser method?)
{
    AddUser(name, description); <- these parameters come from what I'm trying to do

}
```

Is what  am trying to achieve possible?

Comment: This is not a feature of C# nor Visual Studio.  Perhaps a VS plugin can do this.

Comment: @Dan-o Well.. there's `params` ... but thats yuck.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: yeah, yuck.  And doesn't address the OPs use case.

Comment: It would allow the "pass-through" style of the string arguments the OP was looking to achieve .. albeit, in a horrible way.

Comment: Why not just overload the method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd rather implement (*extract*) a *class* for these parameters:

```
 (string name, string description) -> class
```

The class itself could be something like that

```
public class User {
  ...
  public String Name {...}
  public String Description {...}
}
```

And methods will be

```
  public int AddUser(User user);

  public void AddCustomerUser(int customerId, User user);
```

So it's the *class* `User` that can be changed and not *methods*.

You can go further and implement *yet another class*, `CustomerUser`:

```
  public class CustomerUser: User {
    ...
    public int CustomerId {...}
  }
```

And *combine* two methods into one:

```
  public int AddUser(User user) {
    CustomerUser cm = user as CustomerUser;

    if (cm != null) {
      int customerId = cm.CustomerId;
      ...
    }
  }
```